# Get around permission errors

Tags: macos, sudo

In Ubuntu, whever I run into a permissions error I just run the command as sudo at it usually works. Not the case in OSX:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
 From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Aliases/0mq' (Permission denied)
```

as sudo:

```
$ sudo ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
-e:69: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Don't run this as root!
```

Not sure what I should be doing. I run into this sort of thing all the time and while I could `sudo chown` the relevant directories I will be doing that all the time.

I can't `sudo brew install` either as brew 'cowardly refuses' to operate as a super user. I'm just confused because I feel like I'm attempting to do something stupid, and yet the Ubuntu equivalent of this, `sudo apt-get install` is considered the correct way to install new applications?

I could also create a new user who is actually a super user and install things as him, but Ubuntu doesn't let you do this as it's a bad idea and I agree having a user with limited abilities and sudoing only when needed seems like a much better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/` should not be world writable; that's a bad thing - and the error/warning message is quite right to point it out. *(I wonder how it got that way in the first place ?)*

Also, you don't always have to resort to chown'ing directories - you should consider user/group ownerships and permissions as pieces of the same puzzle.

In this case, I suggest you remove the world write bit from /usr/local and try again.

```
sudo chmod o-w /usr/local
```

EDIT:

I found this in the script you are trying to run.

```
This script requires the user #{ENV['USER']} to be an Administrator. If this
sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or however
you please; please refer to our homepage. If you still want to use this script
set your user to be an Administrator in System Preferences or `su' to a
non-root user with Administrator privileges.
```

Therefore I'd suggest you add yourself *temporarily* as an administrator.
I think this probably just adds you to the admin group. If so, you could also
make /usr/local (and any other subdirs thereof) group owned/writable by anyone
in the admin group.

```
sudo chgrp admin /usr/local
sudo chmod g+w /usr/local
```

This would be much more acceptable from a security point of view than
blanket changes.
I've seen some "solutions" where people chown the entire /usr/local contents
to their own id.

Tut tut tut.

Or the other way (as the above suggests) it to install as non-root into a home directory somewhere.

Comment: But then I get 

Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local